# Issues with npm start command

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I'm trying to set up a server using NodeJS but I always get the same error when entering npm start from the main folder of the project and I don't know the reason why it is displaying those error messages.

I'm using NodeJS version 8.

I already installed these dependencies:

babel-preset-es2015
babelify
browserify
express
jquery
socket.io
socket.io-client
watchify

> tictactoe@1.0.0 start /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe
>   npm run build && NODE_PATH=./ node dist/src/server
>
> tictactoe@1.0.0 build /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe
>   npm run compile-server && npm run public && npm run build-js
>
> tictactoe@1.0.0 compile-server /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe
>   babel src/server/index.js src/server/**/*.js --out-dir dist --presets es2015

src/server/index.js -> dist/src/server/index.js

> tictactoe@1.0.0 public /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe
>   mkdir -p public && cp -r src/client/css public/ && cp src/client/index.html public/
>
> tictactoe@1.0.0 build-js /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe
>   NODE_PATH=. browserify src/client/js/index.js -o public/app.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]

Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js while parsing file: /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/src/client/js/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at items.map (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map ()
    at createDescriptors (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at passPerPreset (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:58:96)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at presets.presets (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:29:84)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /Users/danielpertuz/Desktop/TicTacToe/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tictactoe@1.0.0 build-js: `NODE_PATH=. browserify src/client/js/index.js -o public/app.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tictactoe@1.0.0 build-js script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/danielpertuz/.npm/_logs/2019-05-18T21_38_38_944Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tictactoe@1.0.0 build: `npm run compile-server && npm run public && npm run build-js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tictactoe@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/danielpertuz/.npm/_logs/2019-05-18T21_38_38_977Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tictactoe@1.0.0 start: `npm run build && NODE_PATH=./ node dist/src/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tictactoe@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/danielpertuz/.npm/_logs/2019-05-18T21_38_39_004Z-debug.log

Comment: `nom start`? do you mean `npm start`?

Comment: Yes, I meant npm start